# Convolutional Neural Network in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, conv-neural-network, apache-spark-ml

I'm trying to implement a Convolutional Neural Network algorithm on Spark and I wanted to ask two questions before moving forward.

I need to implement my code such that, it is highly integrated with Spark and also follows the principles of machine learning algorithms in Spark. I found that Spark ML is an established ground for machine learning codes and it has a specific foundation, which all written algorithms are following. Also, the implemented algorithms are offloading their heavy mathematical operations to third party libraries such as BLAS, to do calculations fast.

Now I wanted to ask:

1) Is ML the right place to start? By following the ML structure, does my code going to be highly integrable with the rest of the spark ML ecosystem?

2) Am I right about the bottom of the ML codes, where they offload the processing into another mathematical library? Does it mean I can decide to change that layer to do the heavy processings in a customized fashion?

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Have you got a solution?